# How to define keys for changing pages of ROM/game list in an emulator for RetroPie?

Tags: retropie

I wanted to know if there any way I can define keys for changing pages of ROM/game list in any emulator for RetroPie.

Currently <kbd>A</kbd> and <kbd>S</kbd> are used for shuffling pages, but I have no idea how they have been assigned.

I want to replace them with right and left arrow key. Any help is deeply appreciated.

Comment: There must be something in a settings menu to change how keys are assigned. Have you looked through all of the settings?

Comment: I have searched all the setting and config files but i am unable to find this particular key assignment. Which is use to shuffle game list page in any emulator.

Answer (score 1):

I have successfully resolved the above task by editing the es_input.cfg. I just had to replace the PageUp and PageDown key id with the one which i wanted to assign.

Answer (score 0):

Two solutions:

- Hold **a** button on screen and configure your keyboard
- Edit ~/.emulationstation/es_input.cfg file.

You can read more about it on: 
http://emulationstation.org/
and
https://github.com/Aloshi/EmulationStation#configuring

Comment: But es_input.cfg file does not list 'A' and 'S' keys any where, but they are responsible for shuffling/turning game list pages in any emulator.

Comment: Thank you Huczu for your help editing es_input.cfg has done the trick.